# Fetching mongo data in specific format

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

I have a mongo collection named 'demo', which is having the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d600182c44a11cec2b9ac5"),
    "User_ID" : "user-12",
    "Status" : {
        "User_Status" : "Registered",
        "Location" : "USA"
    }
}
```

I have used the following mongo query to fetch data:

```
db.demo.find({},
  {
      User_ID:1,
      "Status.User_Status":1
  })
```

The output of above query is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d600182c44a11cec2b9ac5"),
    "User_ID" : "user-12",
    "Status" : {
        "User_Status" : "Registered"
    }
}
```

But my requirement is to achieve the following output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d600182c44a11cec2b9ac5"),
    "User_ID" : "user-12",
    "User_Status" : "Registered"

}
```

Is there any way to disable to parent document (Status) and get only result for sub-document "User_Status". Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `aggregate` with `project` instead of `find`

Use the below command get your desired result :

```
db.dummy.aggregate( 
{
    $project:
    {
        User_ID:1,
        User_Status:"$Status.User_Status"
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks, its working fine using aggregate function and showing desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregate instead find and project operator.

```
db.demo.aggregate( {$project: {User_Status:'$Status.User_Status', User_ID:'$User_ID'}} );
```

Comment: Thanks, but using this query, i am getting following result: 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d600182c44a11cec2b9ac5")
    "User_ID" : "user-12"
}

as it is not displaying user_status.

Comment: sorry, i was using other scenario, this query showing correct result. Thanks!